# Read text file into string. C++ ifstream

Tags: c++, ifstream

```
void docDB(){
     int sdb = 0;
     ifstream dacb("kitudacbiet.txt");
     if(!dacb.is_open())
         cout<<"Deo doc dc file"<<endl;
     else{
          while(!dacb.eof()){
               dacb>>dbiet[sdb].kitu;
               dacb>>dbiet[sdb].mota;
               //getline(dacb,dbiet[sdb].mota);
               /*
               string a="";
               while((dacb>>a)!= '\n'){
                //strcat(dbiet[sdb].mota,a);
                dbiet[sdb].mota+=a;
               }
               */
               sdb++;
          }
     }

}
```

Text file: "kitudacbiet.txt"

```
\ Dau xuyet phai
@ Dau @
# Dau #
$ Ky hieu $
( Dau mo ngoac
) Dau dong ngoac
```

[image: Screen]

I want read firt string of line into dbiet[sdb].kitu and the rest of line into dbiet[sdb].mota

Example: line 1 =   \ Dau xuyet phai

dbiet[sdb].kitu = "\" and dbiet[sdb].mota = "Dau xuyet phai"

I would like to read line by line until i met downline character ('\n'). How to do this.
Sorry my english not good.Thank

Comment: You're asking for bugs with `while (!eof())`.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking!

Comment: No. I want read firt string of line into dbiet[sdb].kitu and the rest of line into dbiet[sdb].mota
Example: line \ Dau xuyet phai
dbiet[sdb].kitu = "\" and dbiet[sdb].mota = "Dau xuyet phai"
Thank for help.

Comment: `eof()` is always wrong.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To read a whole line from a file into a string, use `std::getline` like so:

```
 std::ifstream file("my_file");
 std::string temp;
 std::getline(file, temp);
```

You can do this in a loop to until the end of the file like so:

```
 std::ifstream file("my_file");
 std::string temp;
 while(std::getline(file, temp)) {
      //Do with temp
 }
```

### References

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: I tried use your code but application just read the last line

Comment: @HoangQBH Can you show the input you want, the desired output (not the incorrect output) and the code you have tried with `std::getline`

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are trying to parse each line.  You've been shown by another answer how to use `getline` in a loop to seperate each line.  The other tool you are going to want is `istringstream`, to seperate each token.

```
std::string line;
while(std::getline(file, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::string token;
    while (iss >> token)
    {
        // do something with token
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried use your code but application can just read the last line

Comment: `ostringstream`*

Answer (score 1):

`getline(fin, buffer, '\n')`


where `fin` is opened file(ifstream object) and `buffer` is of `string/char` type where you want to copy line.